# Custom entity lookup fails on PUT calls with ConversionFailedException

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I have an issue very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40990793/spring-data-rest-and-custom-entity-lookup-provided-id-of-the-wrong-type), but not quite. I want to use a string-based external id, so set up a custom `EntityLookup` configuration as in [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#_customizing_item_resource_uris).

This works great for `GET`, `POST`, and `DELETE`, but `PUT` fails with a `ConversionFailedException`.

I can reproduce the error with the following minimal config to use the `username` as the field to lookup up on:

User.java

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String fullName;
}
```

UserRepo.java

```
@RepositoryRestResource(exported = true)
public interface UserRepo extends PagingAndSortingRepository<User, Long> {
    Optional<User> findByUsername(String username);
}
```

SpringDataRestCustomization.java

```
public class SpringDataRestCustomization implements RepositoryRestConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
        config.withEntityLookup()
        .forRepository(UserRepo.class, User::getUsername, UserRepo::findByUsername);
    }
}
```

I can then `POST` new records and fetch them via `GET /users/username`, but a `PUT` to an existing resource gives the following error:

```
o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestExceptionHandler : Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Long] for value 'username'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "username"

org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Long] for value 'username'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "username"
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionUtils.invokeConverter(ConversionUtils.java:46) ~[spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:191) ~[spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:174) ~[spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ConvertingPropertyAccessor.convertIfNecessary(ConvertingPropertyAccessor.java:123) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ConvertingPropertyAccessor.setProperty(ConvertingPropertyAccessor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.PersistentEntityResourceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.lambda$resolveArgument$3(PersistentEntityResourceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.java:149) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:183) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.PersistentEntityResourceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(PersistentEntityResourceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.java:146) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:126) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
```

Answer (score 0):

That's definitely a bug.

It happens because `PUT repository/{id}` endpoint can be used also for creating a new entity with the given id.
And because of that, during a PUT request it tries to put the id from the URL into the id property of the object. But - because you have a unique EntityLookup - the URL fragment is NOT the id-property of the entity...

It seems the author simply forgot to handle this case. And as I'm looking the source I cannot see any simple workaround.

I think PATCH requests will still work, so if you can avoid using PUT requests then that could be a solution.

I personally don't like this whole EntityLookup feature. (And as it turned out: Sounds good, doesn't work :) ) I think that the id fragment of the URL should be the actual id of the entity. *Perhaps it doesn't violate the REST principles but I still don't feel it appropriate.*

Instead you can use the users/search/findByUsername endpoint at any time if you want to fetch a user by username, and after that you will have the _self link in the response if you want to modify the object via a PUT request later.

Comment: I did in fact work around this by moving away from using a custom entity lookup. I also filed a bug which has had no activity yet, but if anyone want's to follow it, here it is: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-1343